# Catch errors with Laravel API Resource

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel API Resource and handle the error message by sending a specific HTTP code

Here is my code :

```
public function show($id)
{

    try {
        return FruitResource::make(Fruit::find($id));
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        throw new HttpException(500, 'My custom error message');
    }
}
```

My try/catch is systematically ignored when I try to access the route.

I am voluntarily accessing an object that is not in the database. I have `ErrorException` with message `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`.

I would like to be able to send my own Exception here, in case the user tries to access data that doesn't exist. And return a json error.

Comment: ```return response()->json(['error' => 'Custom error message'], 500]);```

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But the problem here is that I still have an Exception before my Try/Catch

Comment: why do you want to put this model call inside try, catch when this can be handled on the compile time as well,you can just check if the there exists a row for a given id

Answer (score 0):

Try this (notice the `\` before `Exception`):

```
public function show($id)
{

    try {
        return FruitResource::make(Fruit::find($id));
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        throw new HttpException(500, 'My custom error message');
    }
}
```